# chrome extension - will an extension update reset users settings/options page

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I built a chrome extension, available in the Chrome Web Store, that has an options/settings page.  In the settings, people can add additional webpages to a blacklist (the blacklist is already populated with some websites when the extension is initially installed).

I am now about to release a v2 to the chrome extension (mostly css improvements and an additional feature) and wanted to know, if people have added a bunch of new webpages to their blacklist via settings when using v1, will pushing an update to google cause their settings to be reset (e.g., back to the original blacklist)?   The blacklist is held in localStorage.

Thanks

Comment: No, it will not reset your settings. localStorage will be kept. Btw, you can test updating process by building crx file.

Comment: ah, thanks!  I'm just a hobbyist so have some gaps in my understanding.  If you make your comment an answer, I'll accept it.  now I need to look into crx files!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it will not reset your settings after an update, localStorage and [chrome.storage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) will be kept.

Btw, you can test updating process by building a crx file. There are plenty of tools which can help you to make build; ([oncletom/crx](https://github.com/oncletom/crx) is the good one).